# ASP.Net inside Wordpress on Azure

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, azure, iis

I have a Wordpress (PHP) site on Azure hosting at the root of the domain (i.e. http://example.com/

I want to host a completely separate ASP.net application inside this setup at a subdirectory url i.e. http://example.com/aspapp

I have created an additional virtual directory in the Azure portal, and published the ASP.net app to this directory via Visual Studio.

I opened up the root url (http://example.com) and Wordpress still works fine.

I opened up the ASP.net url (http://example.com/aspapp) and I get the running asp.net app BUT it only server the aspx page and none of the other content (so its not picking up images, js files or css).

Also, if I click on a link in the ASP.net app that should take me to a subpage on the ASP.net app (eg http://example.com/aspapp/about) i get a 404 error delivered by Wordpress.

It seems like Wordpress is serving EVERYTHING except one aspx page in one subdirectory

Does anyone know how I get this to work.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ive finally managed to work it out

I went to the azure kudu console for the app, and edited the root web.config file, and added a rule to make sure Wordpress completely ignored the subdirectory

```
<rule name="dataapp" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^aspapp/*"/>
            <action type="None" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="WordPress: http://earselectric.azurewebsites.net" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
            <match url="*"/>
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
        </rule>
```

The first rule is the one i added, and it made sure that all requests to the aspapp virtual directory were ignored - allowing the ASP.net app to handle all requests - perfect

Answer (score 0):

In your Azure Web App, you need to go to Application Settings and configure the Virtual Directory for your app and mark it as a Virtual Application by checking the box. This will allow you to run an ASP.NET website, within a sub-folder, of the parent / host web site in Azure App Service.

Comment: thats exactly what ive done, but wordpress is still serving all files that are in a subdirectory of my asp.net directory. The home page of that asp.net directory lacks the styling you'd expect - I guess because the css and js are in subdirectories, and these are being hijacked by wordpress. Take a look:
wordpress - http://earselectric.azurewebsites.net/
: asp.net home - http://earselectric.azurewebsites.net/data
navigate on asp.net about page - http://earselectric.azurewebsites.net/data/Home/About <= wordpress??